# Face or edge problem ? How to fix it?

Tags: faces, edges

I have problem with a simple cube. When i zoom at max in there is that issue, and i dont know what is the problem and even what title to set to this question.
[image]

Comment: You are probably zooming in too far and the viewport clipping precision limits are showing. Why would you zoom in to the max, and what real issues this causing?

Comment: It looks like your edge is not aligned and/or there may be an extra vertex. Adding your .blend to your original post using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ may help others help you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Duarte Farrajota Ramos is right. I'm trying to make a remote controller and just want to zoom this cut to render it, showing it exist.